# SingleChildScrollView for Column inside Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

In the picture below, what I'm trying to achieve, is let the Green part `Scrollable`, since, in case the keyboard pops up, it doesn't give me the render error.

The whole screen is just a `Column`, where yellow part is a custom widget, and green part another `Column` inside it.

I've tried different solutions.
Wrap the whole Column into a SingleChildScrollView, but I would like that yellow part would stay fixed at the top.
I've tried also wrapping only green part into a SingleChildScrollView, but it doesn't work (The Render Error still raised).

I've seen I could use `SliverAppBar`, but I would like to achieve using my custom widget (yellow part).

I am a little bit stuck.

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AppBarWidget(height: size.height * 0.15),
            Container(
              height: size.height - size.height * 0.15 - mediaQuery.padding.top,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  EditableAvatarWidget(
                    circleRadius: circleRadius,
                    badge: test,
                    border: Border.all(color: test.mainColor, width: 5),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Name Surname",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 26,
                            color: Global.blackGrey),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text(
                        "mail@mail.com",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: size.width / 6, vertical: 0),
                    child: FlatCustomButton(
                      onPress: () {},
                      background: Global.editProfileButton,
                      text: "Edit profile",
                      textColor: Global.blackGrey,
                      inkwellColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I would maybe also think to implement a ListView (?), but as you can see I've set inside the Column the  `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` to have already my UI preference.

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this?

TL;DR: Let scrollable only GreenPart (Column) that belong to another Column (Whole Screen) and let Yellow Part stay on that fixed position

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how I fixed.

I've encapsulated the Green Column Part in a `Expanded` before and then into a `SingleChildScrollView`.
It works exactly how I wanted.

Now only the green part scroll, and the yellow part stays in a fixed position when keyboard appears.

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            AppBarWidget(
              height: size.height * 0.15,
            ),
            Expanded( //This 
              child: SingleChildScrollView( // and this fixed my issue
                child: Container(
                  height:
                      size.height - size.height * 0.15 - mediaQuery.padding.top,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      EditableAvatarWidget(
                        circleRadius: circleRadius,
                        badge: test,
                        border: Border.all(color: test.mainColor, width: 5),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Name Surname",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 26,
                                color: Global.blackGrey),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text(
                            "mail@mail.com",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: size.width / 6, vertical: 0),
                        child: FlatCustomButton(
                          onPress: () {},
                          background: Global.editProfileButton,
                          text: "Edit profile",
                          textColor: Global.blackGrey,
                          inkwellColor: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Simple yet effective! `Column(View1, Expanded(ScrollableView2), View3)`

Comment: Just make sure to remove `Spacer()` as that's redundant with `SingleChildScrollView()`, both implies unbounded height thus one should be used only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/SliverAppBar.html) like you have already tried, but inside that you have [flexibleSpaceBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html) which has background property that can accept any kind of Widget.

A sample code is [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html#material.FlexibleSpaceBar.1).

Answer (score 1):

If you can set a fixed height to the `Column` inside the `SingleChildScrollView`,
that's probably the best, even if it involves a bit of "hacking" as in the fix you provided.

However, when you need flexible/expanding content in the Column, you can consider using a `ConstrainedBox` with **`IntrinsicHeight` inside the `SingleChildScrollView`** as the [SingleChildScrollView's documentation describes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

I've found that for relatively **simple screens** this works well. E.g. **where you really only need scrolling** if you have an input field and **the keyboard pops up**, as in your code.

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              ...
```

Note: with more complex screens, `IntrinsicHeight` might be too costly, see [its docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) for more info.